# Auto-layout constraints added programmatically iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to do some constraints for iPhone 4s. For iPhone 5 and 6 works fine, but I want also for 4s. For 4s the view is scrollable but i want the view to fit.

Here is the code which i have tried :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   if(self.contentView.frame.size.height < 568.0f) 
   {
    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [SWConstraintHelper addWidthConstraint:self.view.frame.size.width onView:self.contentView];
    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:self.view
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                       multiplier:1.0f
                                                                         constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:heightConstraint];

   }
}
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Could anyone help me?

Comment: What happens when you do it this way? Does it not scroll?

Comment: it scroll...but i want to resize the view. I don't want to scroll